# Installing Rectangle, Ovals, Diamonds plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, editing, qgis-2.6

I'm using QGIS 2.6 on Mac and unable to find the Rectangle, Ovals, Diamonds plug ?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find much information on the obscure Rectangle, Ovals, Diamonds plugin but there is Rectangle Ovals Digitizing. 
It's in the repository. The operating system should make no difference whether you can find the plugin in the plugin manager or not.

[image]